# Sort of LineSeries WPF Charting Control

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I am plotting a LineSeries in the WPF Charting Control.

By default the dataPoints in the LineSeries are sorted based on x-Axis value.

How can I disable or change it to a custom value?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638132/wpf-toolkit-chart-unordered-lineseries